# How to start SSMS and have 2 queries open and automatically connect to the right server/database?

Tags: ssms

I'd like to start SSMS and have 2 queries (SQL scripts) open and automatically connect to the right server/database (same server, different DBs):

- "QueryA.sql" | Server: `myServer` | Database: `myDatabase1`
- "QueryB.sql" | Server: `myServer` | Database: `myDatabase2`

I tried creating a new project with a connection to `myServer` and 2 queries. However, when I open it, there are 2 problems:

1. For each query it asks me to login to the server every time I open the project. And even though I previously logged in and checked the box to remember the password, it has the password field empty every time.
2. Once each query is connected to the server, the database is wrong. I have to manually change QueryA to `myDatabase1` and QueryB to `myDatabase2`.

Note: I don't care if the solution uses a Project or not. I'm just looking for a solution that works. I'm using SSMS v18.12.1 on Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSMS Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/ssms-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) for this. You'll want to add the SSMS executable to your PATH variable, then you can call it with a command like the following:

```bash
Ssms -S YourServerName -d YourDatabaseName 'path to first file' 'path to second file'
```

So it might look something like:

```bash
Ssms -S 'SQL-Production' -d Sales 'C:\SQL\TestScript1.sql' '\\srvfilserver\SQLShare\Scripts\GetSales.sql'
```

Comment: How would that work with different DBs for each file?

Comment: It wouldn't, @NickPetrie . You can only supply one database parameter. If each file needs to connect to a different server, I'd recommend using sqlcmd mode and defining what server to connect to in your SQL file(s).